How can I write an array-like datastructure in Java that takes longs as indices using modern unsafe APIs?
Arrays in Java are limited to Integer.MAX_VALUE for initial capacity & indexable elements (around 2 billion). I would like to write a data structure class that uses a long for this instead.
I know there are two methods in wide circulation:

Use an array of arrays
Use APIs in sun.misc.Unsafe to manually allocate and access large slabs of memory

I don't want to use an array of arrays and using sun.misc.Unsafe is heavily discouraged, producing compilation warnings that cannot be silenced using ordinary methods.
Starting in Java 9 there began efforts to standardize & replace sun.misc.Unsafe with the addition of java.lang.invoke.VarHandle in JEP 193. Then in Java 22 there was the addition of java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment in JEP 454. JEP 471 coming in Java 23 is going to deprecate the memory access methods in sun.misc.Unsafe for removal.
So it seems like there should be a way to use the existing VarHandle and MemorySegment APIs to write a long array in Java. How do I do this?

Curious.  Why would you need an array longer than Integer.MAX_VALUE?.   That is a huge amount of data (even for a primitive array)  to have in memory for what one might consider normal.   And due to this limitation, perhaps Java is not the right language for this.

@WJS There might be a usecase where array and indices work together in a sophisticated way. But other than some languages like JavaScript, where the array is in reality a map, Java will reserve the dedicated memory. So yes, for Java an array this big seems a bit weird.

@Slevin  Perhaps a map with modified inititial capacity and load factor would be an alternative.  At least it would support the "indices."

Needing to have a data structure holding more than 2 billion elements is not a weird requirement. This is for the long-existing TLA+ model checker, which was written in Java back around year 2000. It is not a greenfield project where I get to select the language, which rest assured would not have been a language where you can't handle more than 2 billion elements.

I would be very surprised if there was a better approach than arrays of arrays.

incomplete idea: class BigIntArray { ValueLayout.OfInt LAYOUT = ValueLayout.JAVA_INT_UNALIGNED; BigIntArray(long length) { memory = Arena.ofAuto().allocate(LAYOUT, length); } int get(long index) { return memory.get(LAYOUT, index); } void set(long index, int value) { memory.set(LAYOUT, index value); } }

You can use SegmentAllocator::allocate(MemoryLayout,long) to create a MemorySegment that can be used as an array of "objects" represented by the given MemoryLayout. Then you can wrap the segment in a Java class to encapsulate the "array access".
Note this means the data has to be able to be put into off-heap memory. In other words, the data has to be a Java primitive or, for more complex types, a MemorySegment. You won't be able to fill the array with arbitrary Java reference types. If you want to treat complex elements as Java objects, you'll have to write a class that wraps the MemorySegment. Or at least, that's the only approach I'm aware of.

Primitive Types
For primitive types, this is relatively easy:
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class LargeIntArray {

  public static final ValueLayout.OfInt LAYOUT = ValueLayout.JAVA_INT_UNALIGNED;
  
  private final MemorySegment segment;
  private final long length;

  public LargeIntArray(SegmentAllocator allocator, long length) {
    this.segment = allocator.allocate(LAYOUT, length);
    this.length = length;
  }

  public MemorySegment address() {
    return MemorySegment.ofAddress(segment.address());
  }

  public int get(long index) {
    return segment.getAtIndex(LAYOUT, index);
  }

  public void set(long index, int element) {
    segment.setAtIndex(LAYOUT, index, element);
  }

  public long length() {
    return length;
  }
}

There are ValueLayout.OfXXX interfaces for each of the primitive Java types.

Complex Types
For more complex data types, you will be working with MemorySegment instead of primitive types:
import java.lang.foreign.AddressLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;

public final class LargeArray {

  private final MemorySegment segment;
  private final long length;
  private final AddressLayout layout;

  public LargeArray(SegmentAllocator allocator, MemoryLayout elementLayout, long length) {
    this.segment = allocator.allocate(elementLayout, length);
    this.layout = ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(elementLayout);
    this.length = length;
  }

  public AddressLayout layout() {
    return layout;
  }

  public MemorySegment address() {
    return MemorySegment.ofAddress(segment.address());
  }

  public MemorySegment get(long index) {
    return segment.getAtIndex(layout, index);
  }

  public void set(long index, MemorySegment element) {
    segment.setAtIndex(layout, index, element);
  }

  public long length() {
    return length;
  }
}

Better Encapsulation
One potential improvement is to create a Java class that wraps the MemorySegment representing the "objects". This will make working with the array more natural on the Java side. First, you need a generic way to map between MemorySegment and a Java class:
import java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Function;

public interface ElementDescriptor<T> {

  public static <T> ElementDescriptor<T> of(
      MemoryLayout layout,
      Function<MemorySegment, T> toElement,
      Function<T, MemorySegment> toAddress) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(layout);
    Objects.requireNonNull(toElement);
    Objects.requireNonNull(toAddress);
    return new ElementDescriptor<>() {
      @Override
      public MemoryLayout layout() {
        return layout;
      }

      @Override
      public T elementFrom(MemorySegment segment) {
        if (segment.equals(MemorySegment.NULL)) {
          return null;
        }
        return toElement.apply(segment);
      }

      @Override
      public MemorySegment addressOf(T element) {
        if (element == null) {
          return MemorySegment.NULL;
        }
        return toAddress.apply(element);
      }
    };
  }

  MemoryLayout layout();

  T elementFrom(MemorySegment segment);

  MemorySegment addressOf(T element);
}

Then you need to update LargeArray to work with the above:
import java.lang.foreign.AddressLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout;

public final class LargeArray<T> {

  private final MemorySegment segment;
  private final long length;
  private final AddressLayout layout;
  private final ElementDescriptor<T> descriptor;

  public LargeArray(SegmentAllocator allocator, long length, ElementDescriptor<T> descriptor) {
    this.segment = allocator.allocate(descriptor.layout(), length);
    this.layout = ValueLayout.ADDRESS.withTargetLayout(descriptor.layout());
    this.length = length;
    this.descriptor = descriptor;
  }

  public AddressLayout layout() {
    return layout;
  }

  public MemorySegment address() {
    return MemorySegment.ofAddress(segment.address());
  }

  public T get(long index) {
    return descriptor.elementFrom(segment.getAtIndex(layout, index));
  }

  public void set(long index, T element) {
    segment.setAtIndex(layout, index, descriptor.addressOf(element));
  }

  public long length() {
    return length;
  }
}

And finally, you need a data structure. For example, here is a Point struct with x and y coordinates:
import static java.lang.foreign.ValueLayout.JAVA_INT;

import java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout;
import java.lang.foreign.MemoryLayout.PathElement;
import java.lang.foreign.MemorySegment;
import java.lang.foreign.SegmentAllocator;
import java.lang.foreign.StructLayout;
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.lang.invoke.VarHandle;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class Point {

  public static final StructLayout LAYOUT;
  public static final ElementDescriptor<Point> DESCRIPTOR;

  private static final VarHandle X;
  private static final VarHandle Y;

  static {
    LAYOUT = MemoryLayout.structLayout(JAVA_INT.withName("x"), JAVA_INT.withName("y"));

    var x = LAYOUT.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("x"));
    X = MethodHandles.insertCoordinates(x, 1, 0L);

    var y = LAYOUT.varHandle(PathElement.groupElement("y"));
    Y = MethodHandles.insertCoordinates(y, 1, 0L);

    DESCRIPTOR = ElementDescriptor.of(LAYOUT, Point::new, Point::address);
  }

  private final MemorySegment segment;

  public Point(SegmentAllocator allocator) {
    segment = allocator.allocate(LAYOUT);
  }

  public Point(MemorySegment segment) {
    this.segment = Objects.requireNonNull(segment);
  }

  public MemorySegment address() {
    return MemorySegment.ofAddress(segment.address());
  }

  public int getX() {
    return (int) X.get(segment);
  }

  public void setX(int x) {
    X.set(segment, x);
  }

  public int getY() {
    return (int) Y.get(segment);
  }

  public void setY(int y) {
    Y.set(segment, y);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Point(x=" + getX() + ", y=" + getY() + ")";
  }
}

Example Use
Here is an example of using a LargeArray<Point>:
import java.lang.foreign.Arena;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
    try (var arena = Arena.ofConfined()) {
      var array = new LargeArray<Point>(arena, 10L, Point.DESCRIPTOR);

      // populate array
      for (long i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        var point = new Point(arena);
        point.setX((int) i);
        point.setY((int) i * 2);
        array.set(i, point);
      }

      // show modification of element in array
      var midPoint = array.get(5L);
      midPoint.setX(42);
      midPoint.setY(117);

      // print array contents
      for (long i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        System.out.printf("array[%d] = %s%n", i, array.get(i));
      }
    }
  }
}

Output:
array[0] = Point(x=0, y=0)
array[1] = Point(x=1, y=2)
array[2] = Point(x=2, y=4)
array[3] = Point(x=3, y=6)
array[4] = Point(x=4, y=8)
array[5] = Point(x=42, y=117)
array[6] = Point(x=6, y=12)
array[7] = Point(x=7, y=14)
array[8] = Point(x=8, y=16)
array[9] = Point(x=9, y=18)


Notes
Few notes:

The above examples are not necessarily the best ways to implement "large arrays" with FFM.

You may want to have the array classes implement Iterable.

You may want to add one or more constructors that accept MemorySegment to the array classes. This would facilitate using arrays allocated in native code. Make sure the MemorySegment is of the correct size in those cases; see the reinterpret methods. That last bit also applies to classes like Point.

You may want to add the ability to choose between aligned and unaligned.

It may be better to use segment.reinterpret(0L) to return the address of the array/data structure so that the returned MemorySegment has the same scope instead of always being in the global scope.


